# Message datetime in moderator message are rendering strangely

Tags: bug, status-completed, moderator-tools, moderator-messages

Inside of the moderator messages, we typically get displayed the date/time that the message was sent and/or read by the users.  Starting earlier today this began not rendering as a link, it is appearing as html inside of the message:

Below is how the date/time is appearing for the message that we sent.

> [image].

Then if a user responds we get the following:

> [image]

Can this be fixed to render the date/time properly?

Comment: Confirmed by moderators on several sites, using Firefox or Chrome.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Turns out that this whole "do I need to HTML encode that" thing is harder than we thought.

Almost as bad as boolean logic. Honestly.

Fixed in the next build (rev 2014.10.13.1936, meta rev 2014.10.13.2655)

Comment: ahhh, much better on my eyes.