# Bug in HTML entities for badge notifications

Tags: bug, status-completed, badges, notifications

Here’s a screenshot from my achievements inbox:

[image]

The rep gain on the Meta question has the `&ldquo;` and `&rdquo;` rendered correctly, but I see plain HTML entities on the badge notification.

I found a couple of similar questions about rendering in badges being different to rep changes, but I couldn’t find one that specifically mentioned special characters.

I can see the problem in Safari 8.0 (10600.1.25) and Chrome 38.0.2125.101, both on OS X 10.10 (14A388a), but the quotes are displayed correctly in the latest public version of the iOS app.

Comment: Heh, like Oded says [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242000/152859): *Turns out that this whole "do I need to HTML encode that" thing is harder than we thought*

Comment: I just [reported](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/242034/188688) an issue about apostrophes being escaped to `&#39;`. Not sure whether it's the same problem or a different one.

Comment: @MvG yes totally the same, the text was being parsed through a method replacing characters with their HTML code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It was <del>totally not</del> my fault but I've fixed'em.

I am deploying a fix as I'm writing this.

Comment: I saw this on WB.SE and it certainly looks to be fixed there. Thanks! http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/358/escaped-apostrophe-in-notifications